# Running MPI application from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, mpi

I wrote a simple MPI application under Visual Studio 2013 which compiles and builds fine. I'm running Windows 7 on a standard laptop (no cluster).
I installed "Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2" to get the proper MPI stuff and I've been able to execute my application from a DOS command line:

`> mpiexec -n 4 .\testMPI.exe`

Question: how to launch this (parallel) application from Visual Studio 2013 directly?

Comment: You'll probably need to ask the MS-MPI team directly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. I've never seen an MS-MPI question answered here. When you do get an answer though, bring it back here and answer your own question to help future visitors.

Answer (score 7):

You can *run*, just set `Command` property in `$(MSMPI_BIN)\mpiexec` and `Command arguments` in `-n 4 "$(TargetPath)"`. If you want to debug it better try Visual Studio 2010. [Here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7d3a8d9-837a-4f7e-8959-df841dcefb17/running-mpi-application-from-visual-studio-2013?referrer=http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7d3a8d9-837a-4f7e-8959-df841dcefb17/running-mpi-application-from-visual-studio-2013?referrer=http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7d3a8d9-837a-4f7e-8959-df841dcefb17/running-mpi-application-from-visual-studio-2013?forum=windowshpcmpi) is op's (probably) repost of this question on microsoft forums.